# Set character set on Amazon RDS (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.3

I've provisioned an RDS instance using Postgresql 9.3.1 and my application requires en_US.UTF-8.  When postgres was locally installed, I would have to create the cluster using "--locale=en_US.UTF-8".

Now with RDS, my understanding is I need to create a custom parameter group, however my questions are:

- Which field do I need to modify?  client_encoding?
- What exactly do I set the field to?  Can I specify en_US.UTF-8 or just UTF-8 (or UTF8??)
- I plan on upgrading to 9.4.5, will the answers above remain the same?

Unfortunately, the only other answers I have found are specifically for MySQL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is set with the **client_encoding** option in the **parameter groups**. This information is [buried in an appendix of AWS's documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Parameters).

Here's what it looks like:
[image: sample parameter group screenshot]

Comment: Will setting client_encoding to UTF8 make the encoding en_US.UTF8?  Are they the same?

Comment: @Brooks the en_US part isn't encoding, it's for collation (and ctype). I believe en_US.UTF8 is the default when the database (not server) is created, but you can check with `\l` and you can [set it when calling CREATE DATABASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createdatabase.html) too.

Comment: You're right, \l showed Encoding = UTF8 and Collate & Ctype as en_US.UTF-8.  Interestingly, looks like RDS defaults to UTF8.  Thanks!